# From within a function, how to view the result that so far will be returned to the pipeline

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Recently I had to add an intermediate variable to a [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) script, otherwise the [New-Item](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849795.aspx) result would be part of the function result:

```
      # Put in local varible, otherwise we will return it as part of the function result
      $Local:logDirectory = New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $Local:logDir
      Write-Host "Created directory '$Local:logDir'"
  }
  return "$Local:logDir\$LogFileName"
```

While debugging this, I would have loved to be able to dump ([Write-Host](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177031.aspx) or something) the current bits that the function already has queued up to end in the pipeline upon function return.

So:

From within a PowerShell function, how to view the result that so far will be returned to the pipeline

Comment: I don't think what you are asking for (a view of items already output to the pipeline in a function) is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PowerGUI (a powershell IDE), you will be able to insert breakpoints and inspect the runtime variables.

http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/powergui/m/

You can also use piping to `Out-Null`, i.e:

`New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $Local:logDir | Out-Null`

to get rid of spurious output. Unfortunately you might have to go through your code line by line.

Comment: I tried, but PowerGUI doesn't show the things that the function already pushed to the pipeline. And there is no `$_` yet, as this is not a loop.

Comment: NB. You can use `New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $Local:logDir | Out-Null` to get rid of spurious output. YUse that to eliminate anything which could _potentially_ mess up your return values.

Comment: Thanks. That is a good alternative for the local variable. But still how would I detect which statement caused the addition? (I'd rather not end many lines with ` | Out-Null`)

Comment: Unfortunately you might have to go through them one by one.

Comment: Please add that last bit to the answer and I will accept it.